# Hadoop - NodeManager and DataNode don't start anymore

Tags: hadoop, ssh

A while ago I installed Hadoop in pseude-distributed mode on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and was able to start all the daemons und do mapreduce tasks.

Since a couple of days I am unable to start all the daemons. After running `start-all.sh` it take pretty long time after which I receive two times the message `ssh: connect to host master port 22: Connection timed out`. The `jps` command shows the following:

```
master@master:~$ jps
14490 ResourceManager
14070 NameNode
14324 SecondaryNameNode
14818 Jps
```

As one can see, NodeManager and DataNode JVMs are not active.

The Hadoop environment has worked fine until now, and I have no idea what is wrong with in now.

Note: I have this problem since I moven to a new place and am accessing the internet using the hotspot of my mobile phone. May this have coused the probelm? Changed the IP address?

Further info: my username is master. I can passwordlessly ssh my localhost, but when I try `ssh master` it doesn't work. I am not quite sure if it should?

Thaks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this as follows: I opened the hosts file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

Ii contained the following:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
[my_ip_address]  master
```

The I just adden to it `127.0.1.1   master` and saved it, after which I was able to passwordlessly ssh master and could start all the daemons!